# osx: searching/browsing in system folders

Tags: macos, filesystems

I'm looking for something in /usr/bin or /var and those directories are "off-limits" for Spotlight or the Finder. What can I do to search & browse them besides drudgery through the Terminal command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply open a Finder Window and press <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> and then type for example /var to go to `/private/var`.

You can also set `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` via Terminal, restart Finder and then you will see **ALL** files. You could easily write a small AppleScript which toggles this option on/off.